# Is it possible to selectively build WinCE directories in parallel

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I was wondering if it is possible to build (via blddemo) some of the directories (i.e. their trees) in parallel while others not.

I have a situation where some of the directories containing parts of the software have been adjusted to build in parallel (i.e. build -M x works great) while others not and thus I cannot do a global MP build.

Thanks,
Pawel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`BUILD_MULTIPROCESSOR` environment variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee479008%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx), then use the [`SYNCHRONIZE_BLOCK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee479031%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) and [`SYNCHRONIZE_DRAIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee478969%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) macros in your `SOURCES` files to enforce your desired build ordering.

Comment: That isn't what I wanted, this has already been done to some parts and these parts compile in parallel. What I wanted is something like setting BUILD_MULTIPROCESSOR from within dirs or sources to something more than 1 where the dirs can be built in parallel and set to 1 where this is not possible due to the 'historical reasons".
But anyway thanks.